# Firebase adapter populateViewHolder() is never called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

activity layout :

> android:layout_height="match_parent"

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/activity_list_tasks2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_list_tasks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   ... something else...

    </RelativeLayout>
```

activity class :

> rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

```
public class AdminActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView rv;

    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_activity);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_list_tasks);

        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Machinist, AdminActivity2.MachinistsViewHolder2> adapter;
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.post(this::supportStartPostponedEnterTransition);
        Query query = myRef.child("Машинисты").orderByChild("points/itogo");

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Machinist, MachinistsViewHolder2>(
                Machinist.class,
                R.layout.machinist_item,
                MachinistsViewHolder2.class,
                query){

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MachinistsViewHolder2 viewHolder, int position) {

            }

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MachinistsViewHolder2 viewHolder, Machinist model, int position) {

                Log.d("djuyf", "populate");

                Typeface mTypeface;
                mTypeface = Typeface.create("sans-serif-regular", Typeface.NORMAL);

                DatabaseReference itemRef = getRef(position);

                viewHolder.cvRemove.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    AlertDialog diaBox = askOption(itemRef);
                    diaBox.show();
                });
                viewHolder.cvArchive.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    Intent startArchiveActivity = new Intent(AdminActivity2.this, Archive.class);
                    startArchiveActivity.putExtra("Name", viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString());
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String myJson = gson.toJson(model);
                    startArchiveActivity.putExtra("myjson", myJson);
                    startActivity(startArchiveActivity);
                });

                viewHolder.tvPosition.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", position + 1));
                viewHolder.tvName.setText(model.getLastName() + " " + model.getFirstName().charAt(0) + model.getMiddleName().charAt(0));
                viewHolder.tvName.setTypeface(mTypeface);

                viewHolder.cvTo.setTitleText(pointCount(model.getArchive(), Constants.header.to, false));
                viewHolder.cvTo.setOnClickListener(view -> showDialog("Цикл ТО-1", itemRef, model, TO, viewHolder.cvItogo));

                viewHolder.cvKs.setTitleText(pointCount(model.getArchive(), Constants.header.ks, false));
                viewHolder.cvKs.setOnClickListener(view -> showDialog("Культурное состояние локомотива", itemRef, model, KS, viewHolder.cvItogo));

                viewHolder.cvTz.setTitleText(pointCount(model.getArchive(), Constants.header.tz, false));
                viewHolder.cvTz.setOnClickListener(view -> showDialog("Посещение технических занятий", itemRef, model, TZ, viewHolder.cvItogo));

                viewHolder.cvRl.setTitleText(pointCount(model.getArchive(), Constants.header.rl, false));
                viewHolder.cvRl.setOnClickListener(view -> showDialog("Расшифровка лент", itemRef, model, RL, viewHolder.cvItogo));

                viewHolder.cvOt.setTitleText(pointCount(model.getArchive(), Constants.header.ot, false));
                viewHolder.cvOt.setOnClickListener(view -> showDialog("Охрана труда", itemRef, model, OT, viewHolder.cvItogo));

                viewHolder.cvOtk.setTitleText(pointCount(model.getArchive(), Constants.header.oz, false));
                viewHolder.cvOtk.setOnClickListener(view -> showDialog("Отказы", itemRef, model, OTK, viewHolder.cvItogo));

                viewHolder.cvItogo.setTitleText(pointCount(model.getArchive(), null, true));
                viewHolder.cvItogo.setOnClickListener(view -> setSelected(true, true, viewHolder));

            }
        };

        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public static class MachinistsViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SwipeLayout sl;

        RelativeLayout rlDataContainer;

        TextView tvPosition;
        TextView tvName;
        CircleView cvTo;
        CircleView cvKs;
        CircleView cvTz;
        CircleView cvRl;
        CircleView cvOt;
        CircleView cvOtk;
        CircleView cvItogo;

        CircleImageView cvRemove;
        CircleImageView cvArchive;

        public MachinistsViewHolder2(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            rlDataContainer = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlDataContainer);

            sl = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sl);
            sl.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.LayDown);
            sl.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));

            tvPosition = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPosition);
            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

            cvTo = (CircleView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvTo);
            cvKs = (CircleView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvKs);
            cvTz = (CircleView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvTz);
            cvRl = (CircleView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvRl);
            cvOt = (CircleView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvOt);
            cvOtk = (CircleView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvOtk);
            cvItogo = (CircleView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvItogo);

            cvRemove = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvRemove);
            cvArchive = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvArchive);
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, I see the list. But I can not call the setText () method on TextView. Because populateViewHolder is never called.
Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I forget about this:

> super.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, position);

inside method onBindViewHolder(MachinistsViewHolder viewHolder, int position);

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to call `populateViewHolder` from `onBindViewHolder` like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MachinistsViewHolder2 viewHolder, int position) {
        Machinist model = getItem(position);

       populateViewHolder(viewHolder, model, position);

}
```

ref [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java).